# gnome network displays freeze on full hd video

Tags: gnome, video, hdmi

I use gnome network displays on Ubuntu 22.04 with different Miracast devices I stream to. Showing a desktop or a static website works, while when I want to show a video in fullscreen mode (1920x1080, youtube or vlc) the streaming freezes. When i reconnect and show the video with half size of the screen, it works. Is this a known problem? What can I do to locate the problem? The problem appears in the same way at different miracast devices (Wireless HDMI Dongle 4K, AT-Mizhi Miracast HDMI Dongle von Amazon, und Microsoft Wireless Display HDMI Dongle)